# Defining what is a line in Tesseract

Tags: tesseract

I'm working on document recognition for scanned bank statement. The statements that I have are organized by lines, such as the one attached. Because Tesseract does such a good job at detecting the areas of text, it breaks the lines in the middle (I'm assuming this is because of the large white space between the first block in the line (blurred for privacy reason), and the next one ('EUR', or 'COURS').

In the hocr file, the bbox of all the elements in the line are within 2px or so, so I could potentially rebuild a line myself. However, this seems more like a hack. Is there a way to tell Tesseract that lines should be as wide as the document itself? Or would there be another way to go about it? I've tried playing with the psm option, but with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

-psm 6 -- Assume a single uniform block of text -- should work. If not, you may want to use the older version 2.0x, which does not perform page layout analysis.